# What kind of rear wheel should I get for 10 speed Shimano Cassette? CS-4600 12-30

Tags: shimano

I have a 10 speed bike, and I bought a new cassette CS-4600 12-30
I am just confused. I'm not sure what kind of rear-wheel I should get for the new cassette that I bought. I am planning to use it mainly for indoor biking/zwifting.

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me if all 700c wheels with a 'freehub' are compatible with the cassette that I bought.

Also my bike has quick release front, and rear as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, why do you need a new wheel? Can you not mount the cassette on your current wheel? Basically, you stated the model number for Shimano's 10s Tiagra cassette, and any wheel with Shimano freehub will mount it. You'll probably see online stores refer to the option as Shimano HG; HG stands for Hyperglide, which is Shimano's spline pattern for road bikes. If you have a bike with a modern 10s drivetrain, you probably had one of these already. On the off chance you had an older 10-speed bicycle, which is a 5 cog freewheel with double cranks, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: All modern 700c road wheels with a freehub will take a 10 speed cassette.

There is a difference between 10 speed compatible and 11 speed compatible hubs. Road 11 speed drivetrains require a slightly wider freehub, 10 speed cassettes are mounted with a appropriate spacer.

There are older hubs with narrower freehubs that that are only compatible with 7 speed cassettes.

It’s strange that you are asking about fitting a wheel to a cassette. I’m suspicious that you have a ‘classic’ 10 speed with 5 gears on the hub and a double crank. (In more modern terminology ‘speeds’ refers to the number of  sprockets in the rear.) You cannot fit a modern freehub wheel into a frame designed for a 5 speed freewheel hub. Older frames have 120 or 126mm spacing, modern frames 130 or 135mm.

Comment: Well, if the OP really is on an old 10 speed, then it’s possible to respace the rear dropouts and put a modern wheel in. Unfortunately, they would then need to upgrade basically the whole drivetrain to get something that can shift those 10 cogs. It’s pretty unlikely to be worth it, if this is the case.

Comment: All except Campy and XDR.